GSAP target undefined not found when i'm scrolling the website
`const header = document.querySelector('.header');
const letters = document.querySelectorAll('.letter');
const logo = document.querySelector('.logo a'); // Changed selector to target the logo element directly
const websiteContent = document.querySelector('.website-content');
let lastScroll = 0;
const sectionHeight = 150;
window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
const scrollY = window.scrollY;
if (scrollY < 900) {
    websiteContent.style.position = "fixed";
    websiteContent.style.top = "0px";
} else {
    websiteContent.style.position = "absolute";
    websiteContent.style.top = "900px";
}
const ordePairs = [
    [4, 5],
    [3, 6],
    [2, 7],
    [1, 8],
    [0, 9]
];
ordePairs.forEach((pair, orderIndex) => {
    const startScroll = sectionHeight * orderIndex;

    if (scrollY >= startScroll) {
        const moveFactor = Math.min(
            1,
            (scrollY - startScroll) / sectionHeight
        );
        const translateY = -moveFactor * header.offsetHeight;
        pair.forEach((idx) => {
            const letter = letters[idx];
            gsap.to(letter, {
                y: translateY,
                zIndex: 1 - moveFactor,
            });
        });
    } else {
        pair.forEach((idx) => {
            const letter = letters[idx];
            gsap.to(letter, {
                y: 0,
                zIndex: 1,
            });
        });
    }
});
const buffer = 50;

if (scrollY >= ordePairs.length * sectionHeight + buffer && !gsap.isTweening(logo)) {
    gsap.to(logo, {
        top: "0px",
        ease: "power1.out",
        overwrite: true,
    });
    gsap.to(".logo-revealer", {
        scaleY: 0,
        overwrite: true,
    });
} else if (scrollY <= ordePairs.length * sectionHeight - 1 && !gsap.isTweening(logo)) {
    gsap.to(logo, {
        top: "20px",
        ease: "power1.out",
        overwrite: true,
    });
    gsap.to(".logo-revealer", {
        scaleY: 1,
        overwrite: true,
    });
}
lastScroll += scrollY; // Corrected the concatenation to addition

});
`
so when I was scrolling the web there was no error and when I opened the console it appeared 'GSAP target undefined not found'. so what I hope is that it doesn't appear again in console
